# Cómo redireccionar desde el theme a una template dinámica de un plugin de wordpress

Tags: wordpress

cómo pudiera desde el theme redireccionar, mediante un hipervínculo, hacia una página dinámica que se encuentra en el plugin? Muchas gracias

Comment: sería algo asi como una página virtual?  fijate este hilo: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/how-do-you-create-a-virtual-page-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Desde tu archivo base del plugin, puedes agregar un hook, por ejemplo el de setup_theme (el cual, se ejecuta antes de que se cargue el tema) y dentro de tu función mandar a llamar el template.

```
add_action('setup_theme', 'open_template');

function open_template(){
    require WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/mi_plugin/mi_template.php';
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero lo que quisiera es poder poner en el href de una etiqueta <a> un link que me permita redireccionar a esa página que está dentro del plugin.